# Device Ethernet connected status

Tags: android, connection, ethernet, status

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

result in logs

> android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
>
> getConnectivityStatusString=TYPE_ETHERNET
>
> activeNetwork.getTypeName()=ETHERNET
>
> activeNetwork.isConnected()=true
>
> activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting()=true
>
> activeNetwork.isAvailable()=true
>
> activeNetwork.getState()=CONNECTED

i am working with android printer and i am checking the Ethernet connection status.
i get always same ablove results. when cable plugin and pulled out.
Any idea on how to track it

Answer (score 1):

For check Ethernet connection use this:

```
public Boolean isEthernetConnected(){
    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        ConnectivityManager cm 
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is `isNetworkAvailable()`

```
private Boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```